# JAVA_HOME directory in Linux

Tags: java, linux, directory

Is there any linux command I could use to find out `JAVA_HOME` directory? I've tried print out the environment variables ("env") but I can't find the directory.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`echo $JAVA_HOME` will print the value if it's set. However, if you didn't set it manually in your startup scripts, it probably isn't set.

If you try `which java` and it doesn't find anything, Java may not be installed on your machine, or at least isn't in your path.  Depending on which Linux distribution you have and whether or not you have root access, you can go to http://www.java.com to download the version you need.  Then, you can set JAVA_HOME to point to this directory.  Remember, that this is just a convention and shouldn't be used to determine if java is installed or not.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is no longer defined in Linux systems and is deprecated.

Comment: @PeterQuiring you should cite your source for that statement..   you are quite wrong.

Comment: @harschware When I install Ubuntu the JAVA_HOME is not set, even with the JDK installed.  Also read /usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/JAVA_HOME and it says the JAVA_HOME should no longer be needed (legacy).

Comment: @PeterQuiring Thanks Peter, unfortunately I don't have easy access to that file.  Perhaps there is an effort to deprecate it in Java 8, but the shear number of tools that rely on JAVA_HOME will mandate a need to continue to define the variable for many years yet...

Comment: @harschware It could be just an Ubuntu thing.  Maybe other distros still define it.

Comment: JAVA_HOME should not be set, java knows where it is installed. if you need to find out you might use: java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep "java.home" as Parth suggested below.

Comment: Maven installation documentation step 1 says "Ensure JAVA_HOME environment variable is set"

Answer (score 118):

On Linux you can run `$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac))))`

On Mac you can run `$(dirname $(readlink $(which javac)))/java_home`

I'm not sure about windows but I imagine `where javac` would get you pretty close

Comment: This is a great solution, but remember to use the canonical flag for readlink as Java can be set up with multiple links, so use `$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac))))` on Linux instead

Comment: Thanks @MatthewO'Riordan!  I added the `-f` flag for the linux command.  Note that `readlink` on mac is not the `GNU` version so I excluded `-f` for the mac version of the script.  Mac users that have the `GNU` version of `readlink` installed via brew can use `-f`.

Comment: This is particularly nice for people who use /etc/alternatives to manage different java versions.

Comment: Worked fine on Mac OS

Comment: On OSX specifically, the following is preferred: `/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8` for example to display JDK 1.8's home.

Comment: This is the best solution to find any home paths. I use it frequently for java, maven, and whatnot! Thank you!

Comment: I get this: "-bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64: Is a directory"

Comment: Ah, nevermind, the intention is clearer with an echo before it: `echo $(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac))))`

Answer (score 84):

Just another solution, this one's cross platform (uses `java`), and points you to the location of the jre.

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'
```

Outputs all of `java`'s current settings, and finds the one called `java.home`.

For windows, you can go with findstr instead of grep.

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | findstr "java.home"
```

Comment: I've reseached a lot of ways to find JAVA_HOME and I think this is one of the best! Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this started working with JDK1.7 (IIRC). Before that you would have needed to call: `jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));'`. In both cases, for 'cross-platform' aspects, it is recommendable to prepend a `/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: Holy moly this one works better than all the others, thanks!

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: On the nix example, redirecting ```stdout``` to ```/dev/null``` seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 35):

I know this is late, but this command searches the /usr/ directory to find java for you

```
sudo find /usr/ -name *jdk
```

Results to

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

FYI, if you are on a Mac, currently JAVA_HOME is located at

`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home`

Comment: Had to use 

sudo find / -name *javac 

to find the oracle VM I had installed

Comment: You might want to try `sudo find /usr/ -name *jdk*` as my path was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`.

Answer (score 12):

To show the value of an environment variable you use:

> echo $VARIABLE

so in your case will be:

> echo $JAVA_HOME

In case you don't have it setted, you can add in your `.bashrc` file:

> export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")

and it will dynamically change when you update your packages.

Comment: Unsafe sed command: what if /usr/bin/java was a symlink to `/usr/bin/java-8/bin/java`? You'd get the output `/usr/-8/bin/java`.

Comment: Fantastic Solution! if you want to use jdk as home instead of jre just tweak  readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:jre/bin/java::"

Answer (score 10):

If `$JAVA_HOME` is defined in your environment...

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
$ # I am not lucky...
```

You can guess it from the classes that are loaded.

```
$ java -showversion -verbose 2>&1 | head -1
[Opened /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

This method ensures you find the correct `jdk`/`jre` used in case there are multiple installations.

Or using `strace`:

```
$ strace -e open java -showversion 2>&1 | grep -m1 /jre/
open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75.x86_64/jre/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 3):

On the Terminal, type:

echo "$JAVA_HOME"

If you are not getting anything, then your environment variable JAVA_HOME has not been set. You can try using "locate java" to try and discover where your installation of Java is located.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set your JAVA_HOME

- Korn and bash shells:export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
- Bourne shell:JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir;export JAVA_HOME
- C shell:setenv JAVA_HOME jdk-install-dir

Answer (score 1):

Here's an improvement, grabbing just the directory to stdout:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 \
   | sed '/^[[:space:]]*java\.home/!d;s/^[[:space:]]*java\.home[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*//'
```

Comment: A bit shorter, though with three forks instead of two, is the following: `: ${JAVA_HOME:=$(/usr/bin/env java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep "java.home" | cut -d"=" -f2)}`

Comment: If one needs to export the path directly: `export $(/usr/bin/env java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep "java.home" | sed -e 's/java.home/JAVA_HOME/;s/ //g;')`

Answer (score 1):

You can check from the command line by executing this command `echo $JAVA_HOME`. If Java is installed but the path is not set, you need to identify the path to your java installation. I prefer using `sudo update-alternatives --config java` which lists all installed versions with current active one marked and provides dialog to switch:

```
There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.14.0.9-2.fc35.x86_64/bin/java)
   2           java-17-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.2.0.8-1.fc35.x86_64/bin/java)
*+ 3           /usr/java/jdk-17.0.2/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

from the above list, you can select the version of java you want to be the default. To set the `JAVA_HOME` to option 3 for instance you can do it this way `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-17.0.2`

Answer (score -1):

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Print-bash-environment.html#Print-bash-environment

If you really want to get some info about your BASH put that script in your .bashrc and watch it fly by. You can scroll around and look it over.