# Hadoop 2.x Multinode cluster Installation

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I am new for hadoop. I found some links in the web about the installation of hadoop 2.x multinode cluster. My doubt is after installing JVM on all nodes, creating same user name, ssh config, configuring on all nodes, how can I connect or configure client machine to the cluster in order to copy data from local to hdfs?

Comment: i hope following link will clarify your issue..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252349/hadoop-client-node-configuration

Answer (score 0):

First copy your local directory to a directory on the namenode that is not being used by any of the Yarn processes:

```
rsync -a <local_dir> <user>@<namenode>:/path/to/dest/
```

Then login to the namenode and run:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/to/dest hdfs:///path/to/hdfs
```