# Where to install Java on multi-node hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

In a multi-node hadoop cluster where there are multiple slave nodes, one master node, and one client node, where all do we need java to be installed?

Also is that we need hadoop to be installed only on the client node? I get confused after going through sites where they mention that we first need to install Java but it does not mention on which node do we need to install it.

Comment: Java is the main prerequisite for Hadoop. For both Master and all the slave Java need to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is prerequisite to run Hadoop. You need to install java in all the machines even in client also.

Coming to client configuration. In client machine no need to install Hadoop. It is just to communicate with the Hadoop cluster

Check below links for more

[Hadoop Client Node Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252349/hadoop-client-node-configuration)

https://pravinchavan.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/submitting-hadoop-job-from-client-machine/

Comment: Got it. So the same goes for installing hadoop package on all the machines, but only certain processes will run on the machine depending on their roles as defined in the config files, right?

Answer (score 0):

Java is the pre-requisite to run hadoop. It should be installed on all Master and slave node.

You can refer the document for [Hadoop MultiNode cluster setup](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) for more details.

Comment: So the same goes for installing hadoop package on all the machines, but only certain processes will run on the machine depending on their roles as defined in the config files, right?

Comment: yeah, absolutely correct..  Master node will run its services, Slave node will run its services

Answer (score 0):

JDK should be installed on all the nodes as it is the primary requirement for Hadoop to work.
Make sure you install the same version of Java in all the nodes.

Oracle Java is preferred over openjdk