# JAVA_HOME doesn't take effect in Linux

Tags: linux, java-home

please see my command output below:

```
steven81@LinuxVMzhexin:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/jdk-10.0.1
steven81@LinuxVMzhexin:~$ cd /usr/local/jdk-10.0.1/
steven81@LinuxVMzhexin:/usr/local/jdk-10.0.1$ ls -l
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 23:52 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Jun 12 23:52 conf
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun 12 23:52 include
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 23:52 jmods
drwxr-xr-x 101 root root 4096 Jun 12 23:52 legal
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root 4096 Jun 12 23:52 lib
-r--r--r--   1 root root  158 Jun 12 23:52 README.html
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1656 Jun 12 23:52 release
steven81@LinuxVMzhexin:/usr/local/jdk-10.0.1$ ./bin/java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
steven81@LinuxVMzhexin:/usr/local/jdk-10.0.1$ cd ~
steven81@LinuxVMzhexin:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

From the output the JAVA_HOME has been set to /usr/local/jdk-10.0.1, but why I use this command:

```
java -version
```

I always get the output like this:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA_HOME directory in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1117398/608639), [How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24641536/608639), [JAVA_HOME and PATH are set but java -version still shows the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14119983/608639), [What is JAVA\_HOME? How does the JVM find the javac path stored in JAVA\_HOME?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2025290/608639), etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than JAVA_HOME you might need JAVA_PATH as well. Here what works on my system:

Add following to your `~/.profile` file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/jdk-10.0.1/bin:$PATH"
export JAVA_PATH="/usr/local/jdk-10.0.1"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk-10.0.1"
```

It would be much better if you rename your `/usr/local/jdk-10.0.1` to something like `/usr/local/jdk10`.

*From where the `JAVA_PATH` came?*

I don't remember well but this has problem with some previously installed `openjdk`. For most of user's `JAVA_PATH` is not required but all I know is, it helped me solve my problem.