# Gradle say Java home is different in macOS Catalina

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

Gradle say Java home is different in macOS Catalina.
[image]

But `/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home` is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

```
The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
Java home is different.
Expecting: '/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home' but was: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home'.
Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
```

I have done the following, but it does not solve the problem.

1. Add gradle.properties in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.java.home=/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

2. Set IDEA Project Gradle JVM
   [image]
3. Set JAVA Home for project structure
   [image]
4. Export JAVA_HOME in .zshrc

```
Export JAVA_HOME=/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Environment

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-07-10 20:38:12 UTC
Revision:     3245f748c7061472da4dc184991919810f7935a5

Kotlin:       1.3.31
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          12.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 12.0.2+10)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15 x86_64
```

Comment: Seems that Gradle tooling API (which IDE uses) does not handle such kind of links correctly. Reported the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187229 for investigation and tracking of it in IDE's side.

Comment: @Andrey https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10041 But I also get the same error with the command line. macOS is really a bugOS. I have given up on gradle and compiled successfully with maven.

Comment: you should not set JAVA_HOME nowadays, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117398/java-home-directory-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

you should *not* set JAVA_HOME nowadays, java knows where it is installed. see here: [JAVA_HOME directory in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117398/java-home-directory-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. Open Module Settings
2. Under Build, Tools and Deployment, Go to Gradle Settings
3. Change the Gradle JVM dropdown to the expected JVM from the error log
4. Apply an Rebuild