# No compiler is provided in this environment, although I can build other project

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have a project in java spring with intellij idea,

when I have import maven dependencies gave me this error:

> Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6

although this plugin exist in .m2 folder

when I have build project by bash out of itellij gave me:

```
$ mvn clean package && mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< com.loya:spring-jpa-oracle-demo >-------------------
[INFO] Building spring-jpa-oracle-demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ spring-jpa-oracle-demo ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\spring\apptracking\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ spring-jpa-oracle-demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ spring-jpa-oracle-demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to D:\spring\apptracking\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.467 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-31T16:13:50+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project spring-jpa-oracle-demo: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

when I have to run the project by intellij gave me:

[I have upload the output here](https://docdro.id/7wSoNzW)

log file output:

```
2019-08-31 16:23:06,993 [1871438]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'D:\spring\apptracking' apptrackinglibraryTable took 11 ms 
2019-08-31 16:23:07,069 [1871514]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2019-08-31 16:23:07,631 [1872076]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/lib/tools.jar 
2019-08-31 16:23:07,709 [1872154]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-08-31 16:23:07,709 [1872154]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-08-31 16:23:07,709 [1872154]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-08-31 16:23:12,358 [1876803]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-08-31 16:23:12,364 [1876809]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 5228 ms: 0 min 5sec 
2019-08-31 16:23:12,490 [1876935]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2019-08-31 16:23:12,491 [1876936]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 3ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-08-31 16:23:12,542 [1876987]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 51ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-08-31 16:23:13,909 [1878354]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/lib/tools.jar 
2019-08-31 16:23:13,910 [1878355]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-08-31 16:23:13,910 [1878355]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-08-31 16:23:13,910 [1878355]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-08-31 16:23:31,105 [1895550]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 17 ms 
2019-08-31 16:23:31,133 [1895578]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'D:\spring\apptracking' apptrackinglibraryTable took 14 ms 
2019-08-31 16:24:00,974 [1925419]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'D:\spring\apptracking' apptrackinglibraryTable took 15 ms 
2019-08-31 16:24:01,054 [1925499]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2019-08-31 16:24:01,623 [1926068]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/lib/tools.jar 
2019-08-31 16:24:01,704 [1926149]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-08-31 16:24:01,704 [1926149]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-08-31 16:24:01,704 [1926149]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-08-31 16:24:05,327 [1929772]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 4280 ms: 0 min 4sec 
2019-08-31 16:24:05,334 [1929779]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2019-08-31 16:24:06,073 [1930518]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/lib/tools.jar 
2019-08-31 16:24:06,173 [1930618]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-08-31 16:24:06,173 [1930618]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-08-31 16:24:06,173 [1930618]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

what I must to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE uses JDK, which stands for Java Development Kit (probably a bundled one). The key work here is development, i.e. JDK contains tools for developers, most notable a Java compiler, `javac`.

But it looks like your console is set up to use JRE, which is Java Runtime Environment. It's purpose is only running Java programs, but not compiling them, so, `javac` is not bundled in JRE.

Check if the `javac` is in yourt `PATH` by running `javac -version` from the console:

```sh
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_222
```

If it fails, [add](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9612941/750510) the JDK, not the JRE to the `PATH` or [set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2619584/750510) [it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1117398/750510) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1348842/750510) `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. There are literaly dozens of articles in the Internet about Java, `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: thanks dear, but i have done the environment variable correctly and when i type javac -version gave me java 1.8.0_111

Comment: Thanks, was running a `JRE` only without `JDK`, aparrently thiught I had installed the JDK, now that works, On linux, run the command `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless` and it auto installs the `JDK` for your system, change the version as u need