# Maven installation issues: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not JRE?

Tags: java, maven, unix, installation

I'm super new to CS and very unfamiliar with UNIX/Bash vocab.

I'm currently trying to install Maven, and I made a few mistakes by copy pasting old installation instructions (with incorrect version numbers) and now the whole process is so messed up. I first tried to follow the given instructions on the website, that didn't work, then I tried a few other ones, and now I'm worried that I'm left with a mess by following different sets of instructions.

I've reached a point now where if I type in `mvn -version` I get the following:

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
>   This environment variable is needed to run this program
>   NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Originally, my JAVA_HOME was set to jdk-install-dir, which still gave me the above error message. I tried redownloading the jdk (version 13.0.1) from Oracle, dragged that file to my home directory, and unzipped it. Then I set my JAVA_HOME to that unzipped file, jdk-13.0.1.jdk, and updated my PATH variable. After all this, I'm still getting this same error message, and I'm not sure what to do.

For the reference, here are what some relevant environment variables are set to (I didn't include irrelevant info from PATH):

```
~ echo $JAVA_HOME
jdk-13.0.1.jdk
~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:jdk-install-dir/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/allyson/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/Users/allyson/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:jdk-12.0.1.jdk/bin:/Users/allyson/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:JDK-13.0.1.jdk/bin 
~ echo $M2
/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
~ echo $M2_HOME
/Users/allyson/apache-maven-3.6.3
```

One thing I'm curious about: for the M2 and M2_HOME variables, is it supposed to be that one is in my home directory (`/Users/allyson`) and one is for `/usr/local`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, take a deep breath, and we'll walk through this.  Each of these environment variables has a purpose, and once you understand what those purposes are, this makes a lot more sense.  Mixing tutorials is not necessarily a problem, but you'll want to understand what you're doing, rather than just blindly copy values from the internet.

1. `JAVA_HOME` is intended to identify to the system environment where to find a java runtime environment.  It needs to be set to the *full path* of where your JDK has been installed.  On windows, this might be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1`.  On a Linux system, you have a bit more flexibility.  Common locations might be `/opt/java/jdk-13.0.1` or `/usr/local/java/jdk-13.0.1`.  If you installed your JDK somewhere else, then you need to use *that* path instead.  The message `NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE` refers to a common mistake when installing maven -- maven requires a JDK, not a plain JRE.  This error is so common that any time `JAVA_HOME` points to a folder that isn't a JDK, it prints this warning (even if the folder in question *isn't actually a JRE*).
2. `M2_HOME` is supposed to be set to the *full path* where maven is installed (i.e. the place where you unzipped it).  This more or less helps maven "find itself" if it should need to for whatever reason.  Strictly speaking, this one isn't necessary.  (It's not set on my system, and maven works fine for me).  It's mostly a convenience for setting the *next* environment variable.
3. `M2` is the *full path* to the folder where the maven executable is.  This will *almost always* be `$M2_HOME/bin`, but it's certainly possible to do weird things, and this will let you work around those situations.  Obviously, this won't work if you didn't specify `$M2_HOME`.  This one isn't strictly necessary, either, and is mostly a convenient way of setting up the next one.
4. `PATH` is where your Linux system looks to find programs to run when you type their name on the command line.  For ease of use, you'll want to make sure that the maven and java executables are included somewhere in the `:` delimited list.  Most Linux distributions already have a default `PATH` set up for you in a shell resource file of some kind.  You'll want to refer to their documentation for how to add another entry to the path, but a common idiom would be `PATH=$PATH:$M2` (which would append the value of `$M2` to the value of `$PATH` and then store the result back into `PATH`.  If you didn't set up `$M2` or `$M2_HOME`, you'll need to do something else.

So, TL;DR, if you installed your JDK in `/opt/java/jdk-13.0.1` and unzipped maven into `/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3`, your *bear minimum* working values are:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk-13.0.1
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
```

And if you wanted a complete set

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk-13.0.1
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2
```

It's worth noting that most Java IDEs will include a GUI for setting up maven and Java within the IDE (the settings will typically only work *within that IDE*).  It's often much easier for beginners to get up and running that way.

Answer (score 0):

$JAVA_HOME should be a full path, not the dir name.

```
scream@kafka1:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/java/jdk-11.0.5/
scream@kafka1:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on Ubuntu 20, and my own issue was about the jdk version located in the JAVA_HOME variable, which wasn't the right version. This was my trip around that issue:

First, What is the JAVA_HOME value?

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
$ /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.10
```

Next question/step, where is the Java app pointing to?
(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42706056/2373421)

```
$ java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.12
```

So, the JAVA_HOME variable wasn't keeping the right value. Let's change that:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.12
```

The test outcome is right now:

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 11.0.12, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.12
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this for future me's bc after all the links in StackOverflow, the solution was to check `mvn.cmd` file on `C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin`...

On [line 52](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5iMd.png) it sets the JDK, but it didn't had the "`/bin`" where my `OpenJDK 15` stored the **java.exe**

This fixed the issue on Windows 11 but it could serve as an idea for other OS. Hope that it helps!