# React Native : installing specific jdk in Mac OS to develop for Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I normally develop for Android on a windows laptop but now I also want to develop on my new Mac OS (But I also want to continue doing so on my old windows), I'm followig the official guide to set up my enviroment on the mac.

**I fear that I will be having problems switching between my windows and mac laptops.**

For example, in my gradle properties I have this line which informs gradle to use jdk 11.0.4:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.14
```

My mac doesn't have this route, so will I have any problems?

On the official setup guide they install java like this:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask zulu11
```

What if this installs another version of jdk, like 11.1.5 or something like that, will I have a problems, and how could I fix them?

Thanks in advance and sorry for newb question, I'm new to Mac OS.

Comment: If you can run `java` and `javac` from a command line, probably you can comment that line, see documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html - * A reasonable default is derived from your environment (JAVA_HOME or the path to java) if the setting is unspecified.*

Comment: Otherwise you will have to set it to the actual location of your JDK. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117398/java-home-directory-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android Studio installed on Mac, it will be super easy. Open Android Studio, find "File" -> "Project Structure" -> "JDK location" -> "Gradle JDK", you can download JDK with any version. No matter how or where you download the jdk file, you still need to set JAVA_HOME environment variable (in .bash file or .zshrc file).